# Update my project with git command on digitalocean

Tags: git, cloud, web-deployment, updates

I have a project made with laravel and vuejs hosted on digitalocean and I made some changes on my localhost (desktop), now I want to apply those changes to the diegitalocean server (update my project for files that were changed only).

How can I do that with a git command?

Comment: Have you done anything with git on digitaloceaan already?

Comment: yeh I already used it to deploy my application

Comment: How did you do it previously? And what’s stopping you doing it again?

Comment: I've just used " git clone ...." but for the updating I think there are some other commands ..

Comment: Did you clone it using “bare” or not?

Comment: you mean clone it from github to degitalocean ?

Comment: Assuming you didn’t use a bare clone, you should be able to pull the latest changes when logged into digitalocean.